# Is it possible to kill a process on its startup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, anti-virus, process-explorer

I have to run a program, a virus scanner, on my work laptop. It is awful, so amazingly bad that it slows down everything else I try to run. It's made me so much less productive - however, due to bureaucracy, I have to run it. When I kill it in process explorer, it starts up again a number of times instantly, and then again at random intervals after that. If I uninstall it fully, I get flagged and get in trouble.

At the moment, I am opening up process explorer every 15-20mins and killing it manually.

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are required to use it on a work computer, this question is about bypassing a job requirement. I think it should be closed. You should take this up with administration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about circumventing workplace policies specifically those regarding virus scan software. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9252/what-is-the-definition-of-corporate-it-support/9253#9253 The fact that you have been warned about uninstalling the software should be telling you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a group policy to block specific applications.

- Start -> Run -> gpedit.msc
- **Local Computer Policy**

  - **Computer Configuration**

    - **Windows Settings**

      - **Security Settings**

        - **Software Restriction Policies**

          - **Additional Rules**
- Right click **Additional Rules** -> **New Path Rule**
- **Browse** to the application you want to ban
- Ensure **Security Level** is at its default **Disallowed**
- Click **OK**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mention Process Explorer - is that the sysinternals one? If so locate the process in the main window, right click on it and choose "Suspend"

From the help file:

> If you want a process to become temporarily inactive, so that a system
>   resource such as network, CPU or disk, becomes available for other
>   processes, you can suspend the process. Suspended processes show in a
>   dark grey color. To resume a suspended process chose the Resume item
>   from the process context menu.

Comment: If it is McAfee then you can't suspend it IIRC.

Comment: @DavidPostill Can't speak to MacAfee but when running PE elevated I was able - as a test - to suspend all the Symantec processes

Comment: I didn't have admin on that work PC, so maybe that was why. I couldn't kill it either. They were time scheduled daily scans so we just used to restart :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a way could be: Disabling the app on msconfig, so it will not load on start-up , add a bat file who will run at the start-up with:

@echo off

ping Freeip -n 1 -w milliseconds > nul

%path of the exe app%.

exit